# Are the proteolytic enzymes in syconiums and nettles identical to those in rennet?

Tags: enzymes

I would like to compare rennet capability under various conditions. The issue is, I don't want to use calf rennet, but I can't figure out if nettle and syconium, which also coagulate milk, contain regular rennet or other enzyme? If so, what is its name? It's quite important.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Rennet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rennet) is not an enzyme, but [rennin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chymosin) is.

Any protease enzyme should be capable of causing milk to coagulate, or prevent gelatin from setting. Examples such as [papain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papain) and [bromelain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromelain) are all [cysteine proteases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cysteine_protease), and all of them will cause milk to coagulate.

The example of fig protease that you mentioned is a cysteine protease (no specific name found, referred to in scientific literature as [fig protease](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20163660)). [Nettles are a highly polyphyletic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_plants_known_as_nettle), and the specific enzyme cannot be named without a more specific phylogenetic group being identified.